# Setting alarms at boot of device

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I have some set 2 different weekly repeating notification alarms at the boot of device with the following code

```
public class MyRebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(firstMonday(calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000) * 1000);
            setAlarm(context,calendar,5);
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(firstSutuday(calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000) * 1000);
            setAlarm(context,calendar,7);
        }
    }
protected void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar setalarmon, int id ) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmClass.class);
    i.putExtra("KEY", id);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setalarmon.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, pi);

}
```

The receiving class is AlarmClass which is

```
public class AlarmClass extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1){
        int key = arg1.getIntExtra("KEY",-1);

        NotificationManager notificationManager
                = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        long[] v = {500,1000};
        builder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText("This is a test ")
            .setContentInfo(" ")
            .setTicker(" Test ");
            .setSound(uri)
            .setVibrate(v)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(key, notification);
    }

}
```

So I am expecting one alarm every Suturday at 23:00 and every Monday at 11:00 local times but I didn't get any notification for Suturday's alarm although as i can see in my phone when I used the adb shell dumpsys alarm command that the alarm notifications exits at the correct time and Sutudays alarm was set for next week

Any idea why I didn't get the alarm?

Answer (score 0):

In `setAlarm()` use [PendingIntent.getBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) instead of `PendingIntent.getService()`.